# In Rego, why is "every" never false?

Tags: rego

According to the [Open Policy Agent documentation](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#every-keyword), in Rego, `every` evaluates either to `true` or `undefined`. Why not `true` or `false`? What is it about Rego that suggests `false` is the wrong value? By comparison, [the membership operator `in`](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#membership-and-iteration-in) always evaluates to `true` or `false`, which is more in line with my expectations for `every`.

I found this explanation of the difference between `false` and `undefined` but I did not find it enlightening.

> The difference between undefined and false is that undefined in Rego is not a value you can refer to in Rego (whereas false is just another JSON value.) With respect to how queries and rules evaluated, undefined and false behave the same. In order for a query to succeed (or for a rule to produce a value) ALL of the statements in the query (or body of the rule) must be true. In Rego, all values except undefined and false are considered true.

Clearly Rego is using `undefined` in a way that is different than other languages, where it usually indicates some kind of information is missing. For example, in JavaScript, if you refer to a variable that has been declared but has not been initialized, its value is `undefined`. In this Rego example, though, `every` is completely defined, but evaluates to `undefined` instead of `false` anyway.

So, in Rego, what is the philosophy behind the use of `undefined` and why does `every` evaluate to `undefined` instead of `false`?

Comment: It feels a bit weird to point this out to a user with 24K rep on StackOverflow, but your question is not about a programming problem. Can you edit your question to include a code sample where this issue about `false` / `undefined` poses a problem?

Comment: @LarsKristensen My question is about the use and meaning of "undefined" in Rego/OPA as opposed to other software languages. Knowing that `not undefined` is `true` (a likely "solution" to a problem expressed as a code sample) does not help me understand why `every` evaluates to `true` or `undefined` while `in` evaluates to `true` or `false`, or what the distinction means to crafting high-quality Rego policies. I believe my question qualifies as on-topic by being "a practical, answerable problem about software tools commonly used by programmers."

Comment: I updated my answer, things may be clearer.

Comment: If it is "a practical, answerable problem about software tools commonly used by programmers", what practical problem are you facing where this is an issue?

Comment: @LarsKristensen I think the question is fine and it's not off topic, there are plenty of questions like this one

Comment: @AhmedSbai you are also welcome to explain what practical, answerable problem is present in the question, that would make it on topic. I agree it is an interesting issue, but a lot of new users with low rep get their questions closed because they ask "why is the programming language like this" - which can only be answered by the maintainers of the language.

Comment: @LarsKristensen bro I don't have to explain, all I know is we're not in court, and from this question I learned something about Rego. how is it possible that someone thinks this is wrong and the question shouldn't have been asked

Answer (score 0):

It is the first time I heard about Rego so I went to their docs trying to help and I'll share what I understood.

from this example here in [the basics section](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#the-basics):

> You can define a new concept using a rule. For example, `v` below is `true` if the equality expression is `true`.

```js
v if "hello" == "world"
```

> If we evaluate `v`, the result is `undefined` because the body of the rule never evaluates to `true`. As a result, the document generated by the rule is not defined.

you can see how you should think in Rego, it is like you put `v` there and then execute the expression if it is "truthy" then `v` will receive `true` otherwise `v` won't be affected and it is `undefined`.

> Expressions that refer to `undefined` values are also `undefined`. This includes comparisons such as `!=`

```js
v == true // undefined decision
v != true // undefined decision
```

> all values except `undefined` and `false` are considered `true`

so `false` is unique as `undefined` but the real difference is that

> `false` is just another JSON value

and Rego uses JSON comparison so it will be detected as JSON and then recognized as `false` that's why we want to give `undefined` instead so we avoid that.

I wondered about `false` and its use cases, I found this example [here](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#default-keyword):

```js
default allow := false

allow if {
    input.user == "bob"
    input.method == "GET"
}

allow if input.user == "alice"
```

here we initialize `allow` with the `default` keyword to `false` so even if it won't be affected by the condition it is `false`.

> Without the `default` definition, the `allow` document would simply be `undefined` for the same input.

still cannot see if this is useful since:

> `undefined` and `false` behave the same. In order for a query to succeed (or for a rule to produce a value) ALL of the statements in the query (or body of the rule) must be `true`.

so I still can deal with `allow` as `undefined`
**note:** the above example is from the `default` keyword section.

another example is the one mentioned in the question, [the membership operator `in`](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#membership-and-iteration-in) with the [every keyword](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#every-keyword)

I found it similar to this one:

```js
v if "hello" == "world"
```

we just replaced `if "hello" == "world"` with the "the membership operator `in`" and `v` with `every`:

```js
every server in site.servers {
  endswith(server.name, "-dev")
}
```

with the same logic, the result of the rule will be either `true` or `false` then `every` is either `true` or `undefined`.

the [the membership operator `in`](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#membership-and-iteration-in) **is a function it is not a concept to define like `v` and `every`**, and it is designed to return `true` or `false` so we use it to define `every`, makes sense to me.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but unfortunately this does not come close to answering my question.

Comment: @OldPro np, maybe I didn't get your point